# customizing stanford corenlp package

Tags: python, nlp, analytics, stanford-nlp

I am using python version of stanford corenlp which uses jsonrpc client/server logic. - [link](https://bitbucket.org/karimkhanp/corenlp-python)

While using this package, I get following result (result is for coreference resolution)

```
Sentence - Bill Gates is richest person, he is also good by nature
```

result :

```
Coreference set:
    (1,5,[4,13]) -> (1,2,[1,3]), that is: "richest person , he is also good by nature" -> "Bill Gates"
    (1,5,[4,6]) -> (1,2,[1,3]), that is: "richest person" -> "Bill Gates"
    (1,7,[7,8]) -> (1,2,[1,3]), that is: "he" -> "Bill Gates"
```

Initially I thought replacing referring entity by referred entity will give me resolved sentence. But looking at above result, I thought this idea will not always work.

So I thought if referring entity is pronoun from I, you, he, she, it, we, they. then only replace it. So above sentence would now result as

```
Bill Gates is richest person, Bill Gates is also good by nature
```

I want to know, can I customize stanford package to do this and get the modified resultant sentence as a result for this package?

Please consider this note :

> It runs the Stanford CoreNLP jar in a separate process, communicates
>   with the java process using its command-line interface, and makes
>   assumptions about the output of the parser in order to parse it into a
>   Python dict object and transfer it using JSON. The parser will break
>   if the output changes significantly, but it has been tested on Core
>   NLP tools version 3.4.1 released 2014-08-27.